# How to make N-level Catetgory Sub category structure in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have database table as below:

[image]

i try this code..its work as list but i want to store data into array.i would like to make menu like e-commerce  and selectbox also contain level of catagory.

```
public function get_catagory($parent_id=0)
    { 
        $this->db->where('parent_id', $parent_id);

        $result = $this->db->get('catagory')->result();

        foreach ($result as $row){


            $i = 0;
            if ($i == 0) echo '<ul>';
            echo '<li>' .$row->catagory;

            $this->get_catagory($row->id);
            echo '</li>';
            $i++;
            if ($i > 0) echo '</ul>';

        }

    }
```

i need array like below..

```
Array
(
    [43] => Array
        (
            [id] => 43
            [catagory] => ASTM
            [parent_id] => 3
            [sub_categories] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [44] => Array
        (
            [id] => 44
            [catagory] => DIN
            [parent_id] => 3
            [sub_categories] => Array
                (
                    [50] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 50
                            [catagory] => BS
                            [parent_id] => 44
                            [sub_categories] => Array
                                (
                                    [52] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 52
                                            [catagory] => UNE
                                            [parent_id] => 50
                                            [sub_categories] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [49] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 49
                            [catagory] => ISO
                            [parent_id] => 44
                            [sub_categories] => Array
                                (
                                    [51] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 51
                                            [catagory] => GOST
                                            [parent_id] => 49
                                            [sub_categories] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Make clear your question with an example please

Answer (score 1):

Pass the catagory result to array to below function:

```
$data['catagory']=$this->db->get('catagory')->result_array();
$return['result']=$this->ordered_menu( $data['catagory'],0);
echo "<pre>";
     print_r ($return['result']);
     echo "</pre>";
```

Create Function as below:

```
function ordered_menu($array,$parent_id = 0)
    { 
        $temp_array = array();
        foreach($array as $element)
        {
            if($element['parent_id']==$parent_id)
            {
                $element['subs'] = $this->ordered_menu($array,$element['id']);
                $temp_array[] = $element;
            }
        }
        return $temp_array;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for Nth level category you can manage using single table the db structure will be like that id (PK), cat_name, parent_cat_id (for main category value will be zero otherwise will add parent cat id).

for example --

```
1) vehicle (main category)  
    - Bike
    - Cars
        - Maruti
            - ALTO
            - i10
        - AUDI
```

in above example you can retrieve all child categories or parent categories using recursive function this function will run until he coudn`t found categories so you have to use **RECURSIVE FUNCTION**

Comment: how to display get n level catagory data into array